# Select top 4 scores by person but need at least two locations

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have data such as

```
eventId locationId score athlete
8739    73          48  matt
8734    73          46  matt
8788    73          45  matt
8738    73          44  matt
8787    73          44  matt
8735    73          43  matt
8789    6           43  matt
```

I need to capture the top 4 scores by person, but at least 1 of the top 4 scores needs to be from a different `locationId` than the other 3

In this case I would want this returned

```
eventId locationId score athlete
8739    73          48  matt
8734    73          46  matt
8788    73          45  matt
8789    6           43  matt
```

I've tried writing out queries that would use a `GROUP BY HAVING MIN(locationId) != MAX(locationId)` but I'm not sure how to accomplish that while also doing an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

I've also tried doing a self-join, but I'm not sure how to return the top results based on `s.score` and `score2`.

Start of a self-join that seems on the right track

```
SELECT s.eventid, s.locationid, athlete, score
, s2.eventid, s2.locationid, s2.athlete, score score2
FROM singles s
  INNER JOIN singles s2 ON s.athlete = s2.athlete AND s.locationid != s2.locationid
WHERE s.athlete = 'matt'
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you really want are the top three scores and then the first score after that that guarantees at least two locations.

This is a rather hard condition, but I think this does the trick:

```
with s as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by athlete order by score desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ),
     s3 as (
      select s.*
      from s
      where seqnum <= 3
     )
select *
from s3
union all
(select s.*
 from s
 where ( (select count(distinct locationid) from s3) > 1 and seqnum = 4 ) or
       ( (select count(distinct locationid) from s3) = 1 and
         seqnum = (select min(seqnum)
                   from s
                   where locationid not in (select locationid from s3)
                  )
       )
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=669d67c3cae69dc9e5a41217d6fd074c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Missing a comma just before the 2nd CTE definition.

Comment: if I replace line 2-4 with `select s.*, row_number() over (partition by athlete order by round1 desc) as seqnum
      from singles s` I can get this to run, but the problem is `score` is really `round1 + 2 ...8`. I created a view with `score` as an aggregate column but it says `Unknown column 'score' in 'window order by'` Same happens if I try to do `order by round1+round2 desc`

Comment: @MattBusche . . . This answer is fixed an should work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks so much man, that got everything working!

Answer (score 2):

*You may use `row_number` analytic function and `limit` clause including a `self-join` as the below one*

```
select locationId, score, athlete
 from
   (
    select locationId, score, athlete, rn, rn2
      from(
            select *
              from
              (
                 with singles(locationId, score, athlete) as
                 (
                  select 73, 48, 'matt' union all
                  select 73, 46, 'matt' union all
                  select 73, 45, 'matt' union all
                  select 73, 44, 'matt' union all
                  select 73, 44, 'matt' union all
                  select 73, 43, 'matt' union all
                  select  6, 43, 'matt'     
                 )
                 select row_number() over (partition by s.locationId order by s.score desc) as rn,
                        row_number() over (partition by s2.locationId order by s2.score desc) as rn2,
                        s.athlete, s.locationId, s.score
                   from singles s join singles s2 
                     on s.score = s2.score
                  where s.athlete = 'matt'
               ) q1
               order by score desc, rn, rn2 
            ) q2 
      group by locationId, score
     having sum(rn) <= sum(rn2)
      order by rn, score desc
      limit 4
   ) q3
 order by score desc
```

[***dbfiddle.uk demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a463bb7f6cd5793a0874fcab261aa4e)

Comment: The part I'm struggling with is in your `select row_number()` section, I can't use an aggregate column as by order by. In my case score is actually `round1 + round2 ... round 8`. I tried creating a view with `score` as an aggregate and it tells me

`select row_number() over (partition by locationId order by score desc) as rn, sv.*
from singlesView sv
where sv.athlete = 'matt' Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'score' in 'window order by'`

Comment: This doesn't work.  This returns the highest score for each locationId, not the four highest scores with at least two different location ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, you were right, thanks. I also met some issues as you've pointed out. and fixed now, can be tried with `limit 3` or `limit 2` for `top 3`, `top 2` respectively, also. Even the `locationId` can be converted to `76` no problem.

Comment: @MattBusche please try again with the new style.